# Armadillo in Win64 (LAPACK and BLAS) - VC++ 2010

Tags: visual-c++, lapack, win64, armadillo

I'm using VC++ 2010 to do some matrix calculation with Armadillo. I find that Armadillo uses LAPACK and BLAS to do some matrix inverse work, it has the .lib files in its examples (lapack_win32_MT.lib and blas_win32_MT.lib). Now, I want to use a win64 platform, but I don't know how to link or find LAPACK and BLAS files to Armadillo.

---

I tried to use the same files (lapack_win32_MT.lib and blas_win32_MT.lib) in a x64 platform, but I got many erros (`error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol...`).

---

How could I use Armadillo (functions that use LAPACK and BLAS) in a x64 VC++ 2010 platform ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 64 bit versions of LAPACK and BLAS, or libraries which provide LAPACK and BLAS functions.  For example, you can use 64 bit versions of Intel MKL or AMD ACML:

- MKL: http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl/
- ACML: http://www.amd.com/acml

MKL and ACML are in fact high-performance versions of LAPACK and BLAS.

There is also the 64 bit version of the original LAPACK (reference implementation) at:

- http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/